# PubNub Checker connection error: System.OutOfMemoryException: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown

Tags: c#, pubnub

Getting out of memory exception in c# when windows Service is trying to subscribe the pubnub request.

```
    System.OutOfMemoryException: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
   at System.Threading.Thread.StartInternal(IPrincipal principal, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Threading.Thread.Start(StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Threading.Thread.Start()
   at PubnubApi.EndPoint.HereNowOperation.Async(PNCallback`1 callback)
   at XXX.PubNubUpgrade.PubNubUpgradeClient.HereNow(String[] channel, Action`1 checkCallBack)
   at XXX.PubNubUpgrade.PubNubUpgradeChecker.CheckIfPubNubListenerIsRunning(Object ignore)
```

Comment: So? Do you have some reason to believe the exception is incorrect? or caused by a bug? if so do you have reason to believe the bug is in the library or in your usage of the library? More information is needed.

Comment: Please enable PubNub SDK logging and submit your logs with your PubNub init code (with literal values) to [PubNub Support](support@pubnub.com) and include a link to this post so we can answer back here when it is resolved. Also please share full code as a text file, if possible, so we can understand the full scope of how you use the PubNub object.

Comment: In general, when you post to Stack Overflow, code is typically necessary. While you are sending to PN Support, please edit your question and provide as much code and context on how you are using PN.